# SignalR warning on startup

Tags: iis-7.5, signalr, warnings

I have a SignalR Hub (called SignalRHub) on which I have enabled tracing to diagnose intermittant delivery failures. When I install the hub into IIS 7.5 (Windows 3008 R2) the tracing outputs the following warning

```
SignalR.ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider Warning: 0 : Some of the classes from assembly "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could Not be loaded when searching for Hubs. [C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\SignalRHub\4ccc0432\cdbbac63\assembly\dl3\8421904d\0082ca11_2b40d001\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.dll]
Original exception type: ReflectionTypeLoadException
Original exception message: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

Has anyone seen this before and if so, is it an issue? I believe all the libraries are installed with the hub.

Any help would be most gratefully received.

Comment: As per exception message: `Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.` - what are the LoaderExceptions?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seem to find anywhere where I can catch this error, to look at the exception

Comment: You can turn on Fusion logging which will log failures. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net

Comment: Also having this issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: this gives some insight : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590597/signalr-assembly-loading-issue-owin